# Python_Selenium PageObjects - TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, class, tuples, pageobjects

Somebody can give a help...

I am just starting to learn more about **PageObjects** and **Python** and I am facing the following problem:

```
[Card(name ="Dormir", description = "Dormir é muito bom")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_pageObjects\main.py", line 76, in <module>
    todos[0].do()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

My code so far…

```
#PageElement
from abc import ABC


class PageElement(ABC):

  def __init__(self, webdriver, url=''):
    self.webdriver = webdriver
    self.url = url

  def find_element(self, locator):
    return self.webdriver.find_element(*locator)

  def find_elements(self, locator):
    return self.webdriver.find_elements(*locator)

  def open(self):
    self.webdriver.get(self.url)
------------------------------------------------
# Locator
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Locator():

  NAME = (By.ID, "todo-name")
  DESCRIPTION = (By.ID, "todo-desc")
  URGENT = (By.ID, "todo-next")
  SUBMIT = (By.ID, "todo-submit")

  #AFazer 
  FIELDSET = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.body_a fieldset")
  CARD = (By.CLASS_NAME, "terminal-card")

  #Card
  CARD_NAME = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "header.name")
  CARD_DESCRIPTION = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.description")
  CARD_DO_BUTTON = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.do")
  CARD_CANCEL_BUTTON = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.cancel")
-------------------------------------------------------------

from element import PageElement
from locator import Locator


class Todo(PageElement):

  name = Locator.NAME
  description = Locator.DESCRIPTION
  urgent = Locator.URGENT
  submit = Locator.SUBMIT

  def create_todo(self, name, description, urgent=False):
    self.webdriver.find_element(*self.name).send_keys(name)
    self.webdriver.find_element(*self.description).send_keys(description)
    if urgent:
      self.webdriver.find_element(*self.urgent).click()
    self.webdriver.find_element(*self.submit).click()
--------------------------------------------------------------

class AFazer(PageElement):

  fieldset = Locator.FIELDSET
  card = Locator.CARD

  def todos(self):
    cards = self.find_elements(self.card)
    # return [Card(card) for card in cards] #Pythinic
    po_cards = []
    for card in cards:
      po_cards.append(Card(card))
    return po_cards

------------------------------------------------------

class Card:

  def __init__(self,selenium_object):
    self.selenium_object = selenium_object
    self.name = Locator.CARD_NAME
    self.description = Locator.CARD_DESCRIPTION
    self.do = Locator.CARD_DO_BUTTON
    self.cancel = Locator.CARD_CANCEL_BUTTON
    self._load()

  def do(self):
    self.selenium_object.find_element(*self.do).click()

  def cancel(self):
    self.selenium_object.find_element(*self.cancel).click()

  def _load(self):
    self.name = self.selenium_object.find_element(*self.name).text
    self.description = self.selenium_object.find_element(*self.description).text

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Card(name ="{self.name}", description = "{self.description}")'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Execution


from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://selenium.dunossauro.live/todo_list.html'

todo_element = Todo(driver,url)
todo_element.open()

todo_element.create_todo(
  'Dormir',
  'Dormir é muito bom'
)

a_fazer = AFazer(driver,url)
todos = a_fazer.todos()
print(a_fazer.todos())

# takes the first card from the list of Card and clicks Do. 
todos[0].do()
todos[0].cancel()
```

I am trying to figure out the error, but I don't understand why I am getting this error. Because the return of **todos[0]** should be a **Card object** that contains **two properties** (name and description), so if anyone can give me a hand with this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bruno Lorena, it seems since you have an instance variable name `do`, and a method name `do()` in the same class. And when you refer `todo[0].do()`, it is taking your instance variable `do` and not your method `do()`. So I suggest you change the name for one of them.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't noticed this. Thank you, @ketanvj. This solved my problem!

Comment: @Bruno Lorena, glad that it solved your problem. Can you mark the answer as the right one so that others can refer in future?